# Store an image within a script

Tags: python, image, hex, rgb

Can an image be stored within a python script? As in can I read and save the base information for the image (HEX or anything) as a variable. I am trying this for printing images to a python webpage. This way the images are not accessible or even available unless the script creates them. I've got what I need working with the images in a database, but I really feel like this way could work and work better.

I've tried two methods, both of which didn't work for various reasons:

1. I tried captured the RGB of each xy of an image and then returning to print or write that RGB xy to a picture. even with compressing the similar RGBxy values, prining the image take way to long. The files also ballon from a 1.4MB image to a few hundred MB's of python.
2. I tried reading the image HEX code and saving it within my script and then an external file. Both methods crash before I can really start debugging.

Comment: Just base64 encode the image and put it in a variable.

Comment: @MarkSetchell how do I go about that? I've done base 64 for simple text conversion, but never an image.